# ArangoDB AQL Upsert how to push a value into list

Tags: arangodb, aql

Trying to use the UPSERT in AQL and successful intill I need to push a value into an list array (and I also need ot check if it exists although I think I have that)

Code

```
const t_list_ = db._query(aql`
        UPSERT { token_name: ${token_i}, type: ${type}}
        INSERT { token_name: ${token_i},
                 type: ${type},
                 frequency: ${tokens[i].frequency},
                 user_list: [${req.pathParams.user_id}] }
        UPDATE { frequency: OLD.frequency + ${tokens[i].frequency},
                 user_list: OLD.user_list.push(${req.pathParams.user_id})}
             IN token_category
        RETURN { doc: NEW, type: OLD ? 'update' : 'insert' }`).toArray()
```

Error is : ArangoError: syntax error, unexpected (, expecting } near '(@value3)} IN token_category

Comment: It seems that this is not just a regular AQL query, am I right in understanding that it's a string that you're using in conjunction with another programming language, to push variables into? What language are you using?

Comment: Side note: you _do_ know that AQL supports something called 'bind parameters' , that allows you to declare all your variables in once place, and then use @variable-name inside your query to automatically put the values you declared in one place, back into that query, right?

Comment: Thanks, its a AQL db_query from a foxx microservice (javascript).
Thanks for the tip on bind variables.

Answer (score 0):

The language used here is Javascript. 
Simplifying the query as used here:

```
let foo="bar";
db._query(aql`RETURN ${foo}`).toArray()
```

is actually using [a specialized AQL-Template string](https://docs.arangodb.com/latest/Drivers/JS/Reference/Aql.html) to generate bind values. To dismantle what is actualy handed into `db._query()` we may use `JSON.stringify()`:

```
print(JSON.stringify(aql`RETURN ${foo}`))
{"query":"RETURN @value0","bindVars":{"value0":"bar"}}
```

here you see where that string came actually from that was there in the error message: `@value3` actually is a bind variable for one of the expressions you've inserted into the template.

So the actual line in question of the syntax error is this one:

```
        UPDATE { frequency: OLD.frequency + ${tokens[i].frequency},
                 user_list: OLD.user_list.push(${req.pathParams.user_id})}
```

and here you're mixing AQL syntax with Javascript-Syntax, which is not supported.